# how to prevent mod_rewrite from handling HTTP Post requests?

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my .htaccess looks like this-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^auth\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^static - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) router.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It basically makes sure that all requests are routed to router.php (except auth.php and static folder)

Now the issue is that whenever I am POSTing forms, mod_rewrite is forcing HTTP POSTS to be routed to router.php.

How do I make sure that HTTP POSTs are not routed to router.php?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can *formulate* conditions for rewrites based on diverse things the apache server offers, like request method or host. The directive is called [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). Only requests matching one or multiple conditions then would be rewritten.

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
 RewriteRule .* router.php [L]
```

`%{REQUEST_METHOD}` is a server variable that contains the request method. [List of methods](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/27-request-methods-for-use-with-apache-and-rewritecond-and-htaccess.html).

Answer (score 3):

Use `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule (.*) router.php [L]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond